# Why can't I use the form $\frac1{x^2+1}$ from the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ to convert the integral form in this situation?

Tags: integration, derivatives, trigonometry

In the question that solves the integral $\displaystyle\int\frac1{6x^2 + 36x + 78} \,\mathrm{d}x$, I first tried to solve it by changing the denominator in a form of $\dfrac1{x^2 + 1}$ to apply $\;\arctan(x)$.

$\dfrac1{6\!\cdot\!\left(x^2 + 6x + 13\right)}=\dfrac16\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{(x + 3)^2 + 2^2}$

Now, in order to make it in a form of $\;\dfrac1{x^2 + 1}\;,\;$ I divide everything by $\,2^2$:

$=\dfrac16\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{\left(\frac{x+3}2\right)^2+1}\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{2^2}
=\dfrac1{24}\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{\left(\frac{x+3}2\right)^2+1}$

Then assume that $\;u=\dfrac{x+3}2\;,\;$ I thought I can apply arctan to get rid of the integral form:

$\dfrac1{24}\!\cdot\!\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+3}2\right)+c\;.$

But the correct answer is $\;\dfrac1{12}\!\cdot\!\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+3}2\right) + c\;,\;$ not $\;\dfrac1{24}\,.$

The answer also explained to use $\;\dfrac1{x^2 + k^2} = \left[\dfrac1k\!\cdot\!\arctan\left(\dfrac xk\right)\right]’$ (derivative), but I wonder why I cannot use the form of $\;\dfrac1{x^2 + 1}\;,\;$ which is the only equation I have known.

Comment: Your post is pretty unreadable. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematics.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry. Is it fine to write it on iPad screen and upload the picture? It takes too much time to learn it now. Or should I delete the post first and after learning it post it again?

Comment: No, don't delete the post. The MathJax is quite easy once you practice a little. Just edit as you go.

Comment: Did you use $2du =dx$?

Comment: @Blaszard, you have to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Click on [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and learn to use mathjax, otherwise moderators will close your questions. This time I have made things right in your post, but next time moderators could close your question if it is unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you messed up in your substitution:
$$\int \frac{1}{6x^2+36x+78}dx = \frac{1}{6} \int \frac{1}{(x+3)^2+2^2}dx =  \frac{1}{24} \int \frac{1}{(\frac{x+3}{2})^2+1}dx$$
Let $u=\frac{x+3}{2}$, Then $du = \frac{dx}{2}$ So:
$$\frac{1}{24} \int \frac{1}{(\frac{x+3}{2})^2+1}dx = \frac{1}{24} \int \frac{1}{(u)^2+1} \cdot 2 du = \frac{1}{12} \int \frac{1}{(u)^2+1} du $$
$$= \frac{1}{12}\arctan(\frac{x+3}{2})$$
It seems you instead used $du=dx$
Note that you *can* use whatever form you'd like to evaluate your integral but what the question tells you to use requires less working so may aswell.

Answer (score 2):

A-ha! I think I found it.

You reduce your integral to

$$ \int \frac{1}{6x^2+36x+78} \ dx = \frac{1}{24} \int \frac{1}{\left( \frac{x+3}{2} \right)^2 + 1} \ dx $$

and wish to use $u = \frac{x+3}{2}$ so that $du = \frac{1}{2} \ dx.$ This makes $dx = 2 \ du$. There's your factor of two!